# Req google appengine collabarate in asp.net project

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to send email with the help of Google app engine
I have project in asp.net
and my skills are .net only
so, please help
Regards,
Sachin

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would just bite the bullet and learn python. It is a fun language to learn and very refreshing and it will give you a lot of new ideas to use when you go back to your.net.

Python is so easy, especially if your coming from a .net angle. I picked up most of the stuff in about a week. Its one of the reasons I rate it. Also it does come with a very hefty library that is comparable to .net.

The environment is a very lean too. I do nearly all my code using IDLE (IDE). The only place where it really does suck is when doing graphical front ends, but since your doing webby type apps from the sound of it, just do the usual separation of concerns and you won't go wrong.

Will stop gushing now, I sound like one of those technical evangelical types that I see and mock.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine supports only Java or Python, so you'll need to write your email-sending code using the GAE API. You could write it in such a way that it takes some GET variables, so you could call it from your existing ASP.NET project.

Take a look at these:

[GAE Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/)

[GAE Python Mail API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/)

Comment: be careful when making an email-sending code accessible using HTTP GET. Could be abused by spambots. Make sure you include proper authentication.